# iptables blocking some requests on ports 80 and 25

Tags: linux, unix, iptables

I have this iptables rules:

```
    # iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     7392 4841K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     250K  531M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       80.1.1.69            0.0.0.0/0
5     6929  360K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       110.50.200.145       0.0.0.0/0
6       23  1404 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       100.40.30.0/24       0.0.0.0/0
7      781 46428 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
8      101  5928 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
9     5664  338K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
10     846 65748 LOGGING    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 147K packets, 381M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      734 46882 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 6/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix `iptables: '
2      846 65748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The thing is the log file shows lines like these:

```
Jan 28 17:31:30 myhostname kernel: iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=78:24:ff:3a:3b:0e:00:09:0f:09:3b:06:08:00 SRC=188.85.58.233 DST=210.6.60.254 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=40229 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56131 DPT=80 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0

Jan 21 22:54:03 myhostname kernel: iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=78:24:af:3a:3b:0c:00:09:0f:09:3b:06:08:00 SRC=217.12.26.61 DST=210.6.60.254 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=41 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35401 DPT=25 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Note that, I have port 80 and 25 open.

Why some connection get block by iptables on 80 and 25?. I steel get trafic to those two services, but I dont understand why ip tables block some of the conections.

Thank you

Comment: You should ask this in Linux and Unix

Comment: @FerNando, are you sure that the problematic lines aren't just old lines that still appear in the log file?

Comment: @Yoel, no, they are not old lines. I just chossed two recent ones. I have same logs today. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will note at the end of those log lines, the packets have the tcp reset flag set:

`...WINDOW=0 RES=0x00`**`RST`**`URGP=0`

Probably, conntrack thinks that the connection is not in a state where this is a sensible packet to receive, and conntrack will mark them as `INVALID`. This means that they are not picked up by rule #2. They also do not count as `NEW` or `ESTABLISHED` when your rules #7-9 in your chain are hit.

Hence, they hit your log rule #10 and are rejected by rule #11.

You can either ignore this, or add a rule somewhere before your log line to deal with `INVALID` packets:

`-m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP`

Comment: So, they are invalid packets?. It may be some kind of hacking attack?. Thanks

Comment: It can also happen naturally when dealing with connections closing and timeouts.